# .NET 'secure' cookies using authentication mode = none

Tags: c#, .net

In my web.config (IIS6.1 asp.net 4.0):

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None"/>
    <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" />
  </system.web>
```

Browsing to localhost/whatever using https works fine. All requests complete successfully. My problem is that the cookies I get don't have the 'secure' flag set. The HTTP flag is set.

How do I get the Secure flag? My implementation of IPrincipal?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978667/how-to-secure-the-asp-net-sessionid-cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see whether the [Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1d3t3c61%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) web.config element also has `requireSSL` set to `true`, because that setting overrides the [System.Web httpCookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228262%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) element setting and defaults to `false`.

Comment: not using forms authentication anywhere in the solution. Thanks.

Comment: This was mostly the answer. The requireSSL was indeed what caused this but the setting had been moved to an sso.config file - so when I put it in web.config the sso.config overwrote it.

Answer (score 0):

Setting this property sends the 'Secure' attribute from server<>client, indicating that the client may only transmit it back if a SSL connection is used.

In short, you can test this by running your ASP.NET application on SSL. A simple way of doing this is by selecting your web project in Visual Studio > Properties > set **SSL Enabled** to true.

Additionally, OWASP has a decent [article about testing for cookies attributes](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_cookies_attributes_%28OWASP-SM-002%29). In the article, the fore mentioned secure attribute is described understandably:

> Secure - This attribute tells the browser to only send the cookie if the request is being sent over a secure channel such as HTTPS. This will help protect the cookie from being passed over unencrypted requests. If the application can be accessed over both HTTP and HTTPS, then there is the potential that the cookie can be sent in clear text.

Comment: Thanks for the link about testing!

Good overview on the required settings to get the 'secure' flag set.

Answer (score 0):

Found it - it was indeed the requireSSL attribute that caused this. However it was set elsewhere in the application (in an sso.config file - where it was set to false and overwrote whatever I put in web.config).