# Setting session cookie to HttpOnly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, cookies

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC server with Entity Framework 6.0. As far as I'm aware, it's set up to be compatible with EF 4.5 (`<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />`).

I want to ensure that the session cookie (ie. cookie that stores the session identifier) is HttpOnly, since that's an industry-wide best practice, which helps protect against Cross-Site Request Forgery attacks.

The problem is, it's created automatically by the framework, so I can't simply change an object's property right after calling the constructor, as is the case with all the other cookies.

In `Web.config`, I've set `<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" />`, and yet - when I retrieve the session cookie - it is **not** HttpOnly (its [HttpCookie.HttpOnly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.httponly(v=vs.110).aspx) property is set `false`). And I don't quite know how to change that.

I couldn't find anything in Microsoft's documentation about `Web.config`'s `<sessionState>` that would change that. Here on Stack Overflow I only found [a four year old question talking about how session cookie is HttpOnly by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247143/how-is-httponly-get-set-for-asp-net-sessionid-cookie), which is *the precise opposite* for me, and [a five days old question asking why session cookie is **not** HttpOnly by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39624162/why-asp-net-sessionid-cookie-by-default-is-not-httponly) - which for some inexplicable reason was closed - without a comment - as a duplicate of the former.

I know [I can retrieve the session cookie, check it and set `HttpOnly=true` on every request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5978751/5282087) (or do that less often with a slightly more refined/hackish filter, or set it manually on login, or...), but <s>I'm not a blood-soaked barbarian</s> there has to be a proper way to do this.

So, how do I set the session cookie to HttpOnly?

Comment: I closed [the second question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39624162/why-asp-net-sessionid-cookie-by-default-is-not-httponly) as ***Duplicate***. The accepted [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2247221/296861) is explicitly stated that Session Cookie is ***httponly*** and you cannot modify it.

Comment: @Win But the problem is, in my project, session cookie is *not* httponly, so either framework did 180 degree turn over 4 years on default properties of the cookie, or there *is* some way to change it and I - or the other dev on my team - has somehow changed it. What I'm trying to say is that reality of my issue and the answer don't match up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***Session Cookie*** will always be ***httponly***. You cannot modify or override it.

> when I retrieve the session cookie - it is not HttpOnly (its
>   HttpCookie.HttpOnly property is set false).

```
var cookie = Request.Cookies["ASP.Net_SessionId"];
if (cookie != null)
{
    var httpOnly = cookie.HttpOnly; // <-- This is always false
}
```

**HttpOnly** value is always false at server-side, because client browser does not send back to server whether cookie is in httponly or not.

### How can I verify

You can use cookie editor such as Chrome Plugin [EditThisCookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=en).

[image]

Comment: So it was an XY problem after all. This was the explanation I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: But I can edit HttpOnly cookies in Chrome -> Application -> Cookies

Comment: Been a while since this was posted and I figured I'd just note that if I give the session cookie an explicit name, then it does NOT show HttpOnly in Chrome even if I explicitly set it like this:
`   var sessionCookie = new CookieBuilder();
   sessionCookie.Name = ".MyWebSite";
   sessionCookie.HttpOnly=true;
   sessionCookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
   sessionCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
   app.UseSession(new SessionOptions() { Cookie = sessionCookie });`

I must be missing something about how to get it work, but it definitely is not defaulting to httponly